# How can I tell if OpenVPN server is ready to receive client connections?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

Specifically I am trying to create an appropriate Kubernetes readiness probe (so require either a command to run or a readiness endpoint to hit that will signal whether OpenVPN has started up and is ready).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if the question was worded in a strange way, but the solution I found that worked as I wanted was to use netcat: `nc -uz 127.0.0.1 443` removing the `-u` flag if in TCP mode: https://github.com/helm/charts/pull/15580/files

Answer (score 0):

From the official OpenVPN docs:

```
Sun Feb  6 20:46:38 2005 OpenVPN 2.0_rc12 i686-suse-linux [SSL] [LZO] [EPOLL] built on Feb  5 2005
Sun Feb  6 20:46:38 2005 Diffie-Hellman initialized with 1024 bit key
Sun Feb  6 20:46:38 2005 TLS-Auth MTU parms [ L:1542 D:138 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Sun Feb  6 20:46:38 2005 TUN/TAP device tun1 opened
Sun Feb  6 20:46:38 2005 /sbin/ifconfig tun1 10.8.0.1 pointopoint 10.8.0.2 mtu 1500
Sun Feb  6 20:46:38 2005 /sbin/route add -net 10.8.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.8.0.2
Sun Feb  6 20:46:38 2005 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1542 D:1450 EF:42 EB:23 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Sun Feb  6 20:46:38 2005 UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]:1194
Sun Feb  6 20:46:38 2005 UDPv4 link remote: [undef]
Sun Feb  6 20:46:38 2005 MULTI: multi_init called, r=256 v=256
Sun Feb  6 20:46:38 2005 IFCONFIG POOL: base=10.8.0.4 size=62
Sun Feb  6 20:46:38 2005 IFCONFIG POOL LIST
Sun Feb  6 20:46:38 2005 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO#Startingtheserver

So `Initialization Sequence Completed` might be a good indicator that the server has competed its Initialization.

Comment: I'm not sure if that line being written is the exact point it is ready? And it's difficult to poll for this on startup (I guess you could just keep reading the file, but not really a great readiness check).

Also if the server ever becomes unready to receive more connections for some reason (for example lots of connections at the same time) then this check doesn't show that status

Comment: Since OpenVPN is basically just TLS wrapped traffic, why not a simple `openssl s_client `like check?